# How to align elements to the center?

Tags: html, forms, css, flexbox

I have two questions.

first,

I have a form and I'm trying to center everything to the center of it and in the same time align the text to the left side of the fields.

I'v tried to give justify-center and align-items to the "container" class and to the "form-style" class and nothing works.

Part of the code and a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/BxVYzv) link

```
.form-style {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;

   display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

And,

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

Second,

I'm trying to make my submit button to get 100% width and nothing - there's space at the sides,

```
input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;

  background-color: #08ABD9;
  font-family: 'jura', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;

  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to align the form labels to the left and on top of the form inputs?

Comment: If you look at my codepen, right now it's the closest (just need to get rid the extra space in the right side). but there must be a better way to do that...

Comment: Yes, labels, legend etc'

Answer (score 1):

Start here: There's a syntax error in your code. The `display: flex` on the container is not being recognized due to the presence of an invisible character. None of the flex properties are working.

[image]

So first fix that. Just delete the line entirely and re-write `display: flex`. You will notice major changes in your layout.

Second, your `flex-direction` is set to `column` on your label/input containers. That stacks your form elements vertically.

```
#fname, #email-a, #phone, #dropdown, #mrole, #age, #textbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

If you want the text and input to line up in a row, use `flex-direction: row`.

Lastly, with regard to your submit button, your container has left and right padding which prevents the button from reaching the edges.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Once you remove the padding rules, the button will extend from edge to edge.

Comment: If i'll put row, wouldn't it look like <label> and to the right <input> instead of a <label> and underneath it <input> ? I want it to look the same in structured, only to take everything as is, an align to center.. .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}  Yet not working :|

Comment: *... align the text to the left side of the fields.*

Comment: Also, I found another problem. It's probably the main problem. Answer revised.

Comment: 1. How did you checked it ? I'd like to learn. 2. And how do I read that error, I don't understand it.... 3. right now all the fields are in the middle but the labels are at the left side and not at the left of the fields

Comment: Search "Chrome Developer Tools" or "Firefox Inspector".

Comment: I every thing tou wrote and still nothing, I think an easy solution is to give exact margin to the labels and input from the sides but I don't if it's "cheating" and if there's right/better solution